# How can I format date time string which is not date time format so that I can use it with pd.to_datetime()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a Pandas series of date time string. However, that date time string isn't properly formatted. Therefore, can I know how can I format the date time string in order to use it with `pd.to_datetime()`?

e.g. `t = pd.Series(['20201023', '20201123', '20201012'])`

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to format it in any way. `pd.to_datetime` is clever enough to correctly guess the format of your strings in this case. `pd.to_datetime(t)` suffices to convert it to a datetime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pre-process the string. Use [`format='%Y%m%d'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) directly in [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
t = pd.Series(['20201023', '20201123', '20201012'])

out = pd.to_datetime(t, format='%Y%m%d')
```

`to_datetime` can also guess the format automatically in most cases:

```
out = pd.to_datetime(t)
```

output:

```
0   2020-10-23
1   2020-11-23
2   2020-10-12
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.to_datetime` can infer datetime properly

```py
out = pd.to_datetime(t)
```

```
print(out)

0   2020-10-23
1   2020-11-23
2   2020-10-12
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```